# Are elements in lists subjected to the 2 gigabyte object size limit

Tags: c#

Let's just say I'm running a physics simulation that uses integers as vertexes on a model. In this simulation I load arrays of integers to a list as the amount of vertexes may vary; like so:

```
List<int[]> x = new List<int[]>();
x.Add(new <int[1]>());
```

I know it's a bit overboard, considering to use 2GB worth of integers, but the model could range anywhere from a single object to entire open field. So, considering this process is repeated enough to take up 2GB, would each element/array have it's own 2GB as it's own object or does the entire list still count as the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is an object, the backing array **inside** the list (`T[]`, so: `int[][]`) is an object, and each `int[]` array is (separately) an object. As long as no individual array is too large, you're OK. At no point are the arrays in a `List<some array>` treated as contiguous, so it doesn't matter if their combined length exceeds the 2 GiB limit.

Note that you can enable very-large-object support in your configuration ([`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element)) to squeeze out a *slightly larger* array limit - for most arrays (not bytes/single-byte elements) it changes the *maximum element count* to 2,146,435,071 - which is ~8 GiB in your case (`int[]`). That doesn't necessarily mean it is a *good idea* to do so :)

Comment: I suppose replacing the arrays with lists to achieve a multi-dimensional list would yield the same results.

Comment: @Texadecimal indeed; but keep in mind that a list *has* an array for the backing field *anyway* - the main difference between a jagged array vs jagged list is : which parts allow additional elements vs which are fixed length

Comment: And seriously AllowVeryLargeObjects!? Very professional Microsoft!

Comment: @Texadecimal the name? well... what would *you* call it?

Comment: Well, I suppose I won't be using polygons that take up 2GB. Thank you, I'll except your answer as soon as possible

Comment: I dunno MaxObjectSize(int);

Comment: I just found it amusing